# How to import a variable from a js file

Tags: javascript

I want to import a array from a js file and it doesn't work.
My code :

```js
import * as dollarsValue from './index.js';
function intiualAdaptedVal(arr1, arr2, arrCid) { // arr1 => changeArr ; arr2 => dollarsValue
    let num;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        num = getNumber(arr2, arr2[i][1]) / arrCid[i][1];
        arr1[i].push(num.toFixed(2));
    }
    return arr1;
}
console.log(intiualAdaptedVal(changeArr, dollarsValue, cid))
```

But it doesn't work:

[image]

Thanks you

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the error message?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using the ES module, you have to add

```
"type": "module",
```

in package.json

Answer (score -1):

**On 'index.js':**

```
module.exports = { dollarsValue }
```

**and for recalling in another file:**

```
const arrayIndex = require('./index.js')
let array = arrayIndex.dollarsValue
```